# Avoid full scan for subquery

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a query which was working before I added the exist condition. After adding the exist condition , its going into loop forever and not getting back any results. I think the main reason for that is the full scan for every row level record. Can anyone please tell how to avoid that. The query below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Basically the condition is that a car can have many parts and if any one of the parts updated on changes for that car, we want to pick up all the parts. The part has detail table and I want to look at updates to the detail table.

```
select c.id, p.id
from car c join part p on p.car_id=c.id
where exists ( 
    select 1 
    from part p join pdetl pd on p.id=pd.part_id 
    where p.car_id=c.id and pd.updated_on > ?
)
```

Comment: i think the main reason of the infinite loop is in the main query PART is P and in the subquery PART is also P... rename the subquery and the criteria, and P.car_id = P2.car_Id

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Modified the query to get all the parts associated to the car that had part(s) updated.

The inner query gets the parts that were updated. The outer query then pulls all the parts that are associated to the car:

```
select c.id, p.id
from car c join part p on p.car_id=c.id
where c.id in
(
  select c.id
  from car c join part p on p.car_id=c.id
  where exists ( 
                 select 1 
                 from pdetl pd 
                 where p.id=pd.part_id 
                   and pd.updated_on > ?
                )
)
```

Comment: but this will only look at that parts updated on. I want to fetch all the parts if any of the parts have been modified for that car. So i need to join at car id level

Comment: Thanks. I will try that .

Comment: it still does the full scan and hangs

Comment: Please make sure the following columns are indexed:
car.id, part.id, part.car_id, pdetl.part_id, pdetl.updated_on.

Also, can you please post your explain plan (if the above doesn't work).